# Can you add new functions to the set of elementary functions such that every function has an anti-derivative?

Tags: integration, functions

Its fairly well known that not every elementary function has an elementary anti-derivative.  The common examples of this are $\exp(-x^2)$ and $\sin(x)/x$.  The general workaround to this problem is to create new functions like $\mathrm{Erf}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Si}(x)$ to go alongside the more elementary functions.  I was wondering if there is a way to add "enough" non-elementary functions so that every function has an anti-derivative that can be expressed via other functions.  The typical solution to this question is to introduce Riemann integration as an operator on functions, and then declare that the set of functions is closed under this operator.  That definitely works, but I'm looking for something that is more enumerable.  Like a simple countable set of functions that I can build everything else out of.  Has anyone come up with a set of functions like this, or proved that making one is impossible?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function

Comment: If your set of functions in analytic, then yes, just use Laurent series, truncated to finite order.

Comment: @AlexR.: I don't see how Laurent series give a *countable* set of functions that meet Joel Turnblade's requirements.

Comment: @RobArthan: Isn't $\{x^k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ countable? I'm assuming OP wants antiderivatives to be generated as (possibly infinite) linear combinations of such a set.

Comment: I was assuming the OP was looking for a countable set of functions that would generate in the algebraic (finitistic) sense an an algebra of functions closed under antiderivation. Over to the OP to clarify.

Comment: I am definitely looking for something more like what Rob Arthan was mentioning.  I am hoping to give an algorithmic description of each function.  Laurent series certainly work, but something like "all convergent Laurent series" isn't quite as specific as I want.

Comment: I think I vaguely remember that the question "find out if this function has a closed form antiderivative" is not algorithmically computable in general for rational fractions of sine and cosine. in other words, that would mean that there are no algorithms telling you how to write the antiderivative of such functions in terms of usual functions

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki:  I have heard that the Risch algorithm can be used to find closed form anti-derivatives in many cases when they exist.  I wouldn't know if it also works on rational functions of sine and cosine though.  In my case I am willing to add new functions, so that changes things a bit.

Comment: @JoelTurnblade in many cases you can indeed find closed form. but if what I remember is correct, it means that there is no way to know algorithmically if there is a known closed form. so even if you add new functions, it doesn't help

Comment: The closure under integration of the set of the elementary functions is the set of the Liouvillian functions. And here also different sets of functions are possible based on other differential fields. The definition of this classes of functions is given e.g. in section 1 of Davenport, J. H.: What Might "Understand a Function" Mean. In: Kauers, M.; Kerber, M., Miner, R.;  Windsteiger, W.: Towards Mechanized Mathematical Assistants. Springer, Berlin/Heidelberg, 2007, page 55-65.

Further large function classes are closed under integration, e.g. the polynomials and the power series.