# Implications of the fact that anti-derivatives form an equivalence class?

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

I just started learning about equivalence classes in the context of modular arithmetic, and learned that the union of the $n$ equivalence classes modulo $n$ is $\mathbb{Z}$.

My professor then applied this to the fact that we've seen equivalence classes before when talking about anti-derivatives - how $\int f(x) dx + c$
is the equivalence class of anti-derivatives of $f$.

I apologize if this is not quite correct, and I'd welcome a correction, because I'm not too sure of the precise language used when speaking of relations.

I'm wondering if because the union of equivalence classes is the whole set, that any differentiable function must have a class of anti-derivatives $g(x)$ such that $\frac{d}{dx} g(x) = f(x)$? I was reading the response to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1370599/268374) question, which is similar to mine, but I'm wondering if due to the fact that we can form an equivalence relation, there must be an anti-derivative for any differentiable function?

Comment: Now that the typo is fixed, you may want to rethink your question.  The fact that "the union of equivalence classes is the whole set" has nothing to do with the question of whether every differentiable function has an anti-derivative.  (By the way, any everywhere-differentiable function $f$ does indeed have anti-derivatives.  For example, $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ is differentiable and $F'(x) = f(x)$.)

Comment: With the edit of the question, everywhere-differentiable functions have disappeared. It is now more difficult to discern what you mean by "the whole set." It is important to define what set one is talking about when one describes a relation. If $\script F$ is the set of everywhere-differentiable functions then the function differentiation is a many-one map from $\script F$ *onto* $\script F$. Which is just your statement that there must be an anti-derivative for every everywhere-differentiable function. But that is not a consequence of the equivalence relation.

Comment: @StephenMeskin so you're saying that my statement is a result of differentiation being a surjective/onto the everywhere-differentiable functions?

Comment: cont'd However, the equivalence relation is a consequence of the differentiation map. Indeed every equiv. rel is equivalent to a map.

Comment: Yes, your statement is a result of differentiation being onto EDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The fact that the union of the equivalence classes is the whole set just means that any differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is in some equivalence class.  This is obvious, because the set $S$ of all $g$ which are equivalent to $f$ is one of the equivalence classes, and $f\in S$ because $f$ is equivalent to itself.  This in no way says anything about the existence of $g$ whose derivative is $f$.

(In fact, it is true that any such $f$ has an antiderivative, but this has nothing to do with this equivalence relation.  Instead, it is true by the fundamental theorem of calculus, since if $g(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$ then $f$ is the derivative of $g$.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So here's where I suppose I'm confused: $\int f(x) + c$ forms an equivalence class based on being an antiderivative of $f(x)$. For example, $x^2 + c$ is the equivalence class characterized by being the antiderivative of $f(x) = 2x$. So if I pick any arbitrary differentiable function, this would imply that it's in an equivalence class characterized by being the antiderivative of some function $g(x)$? So I suppose it would show the fact that any differentiable function, you can differentiate and it will yield some function $g(x)$? Is this what you are saying?

Comment: What you have said is correct: if $f$ is any differentiable function, then it is an antiderivative of some function (namely its derivative).  This is quite different from saying that $f$ is the _derivative_ of some function, which is what you stated in the question!

Answer (score 3):

I think you have your statement backwards. The everywhere differentiable functions are partitioned into equiv. classes based on their derivatives. That doesn't say anything about the everywhere differentiable functions having antiderivatives.

Comment: That could very well be true, although we proved reflexivity, transitivity, and symmetry by the fact that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ differ by a constant $C$, so wouldn't this be about anti-derivatives?

Comment: It only says that $f$ and $g$ are both antiderivatives of their common derivative.

Comment: So the union of equivalence classes being the whole set implies that any differentiable function $f$ must belong to some equivalence class, and that equivalence class is characterized by the function $g(x)$ which is the derivative of $f$?